# RavenDB long response time for query, while was processed on server very fast

Tags: .net, ravendb

Raven.Server started and binded to port 8022. I initialize DataStore in the following way:

```
        var store = new DocumentStore() { Url = "http://localhost:8022" };
        store.Initialize();
```

Then i'm making such query:

```
        using (var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            var result = session.LuceneQuery<Item>("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName")
                .WhereEquals("Tag", "Items")
                .ToList();

            watch.Stop(); // watch.ElapsedMilliseconds == ~550 ms

            return result;

        }
```

And `watch.ElapsedMilliseconds` is always ~550 ms. 
But when i look to RavenDB console i see that query was processed in 3 ms:

```
Request # 170: GET     -    3 ms - 200 - /indexes/Raven/DocumentsByEntityName?query=Tag%253A%255B%255BItems%255D%255D&start=0&pageSize=128
```

Thus ~ 99.5% of time have been spent not in RavenDB. What is the problem? (RavenDB 147)

**When i switch to self-hosting of RavenDB (i.e. as embedded client) everything is okay (~3ms).**

To clarify that issue not in network, http debuggers, dns servers etc. i also tested this:

```
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var result = client.DownloadString("http://127.0.0.1:8022/indexes/Raven/DocumentsByEntityName?query=Tag%253A%255B%255BItems%255D%255D&start=0&pageSize=128");

            watch.Stop(); // watch.ElapsedMilliseconds == ~3-10ms
```

Fast. But switching to Raven.Client.Lightweight increase response time in 200 times (550-600 ms)

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question this is a somewhat flawed test as you're only doing a single comparison, you want to wrap a loop around your using statement and move the stop watch to just inside the loop then print out the time or store it in a list or something then you can see if the first request(s) are outliers and you'll have more data to look at afterwards.

Comment: @Chris, i'm not interesting in building (and furthermore in showing to community) comprehensive performance test. It's enough for me that it works as expected when used as embedded client.

Comment: Are you seeing the same consistent times in a loop? Becuase without testing your code in a tight loop you can't really be sure if you the optimization needs to take place in the code itself or the startup procedure.

Comment: I've implemented a loop for 50 requests inside a session and store response time in array. Results are very consistent (530 - 580 ms). But when i use Raven as Embedded Client results are from 1 ms to 5 ms. Ayende Rahien (on google groups) supposed that this is because of IPv4/IPv6 issue. But then i tested direct http call for the same query inside same my application - 1-5 ms (shown in question). I thought that the main functionality of Raven.Client.Lightweight is just building of such http queries... But seems it does more...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem was because of middleman on my computer - NOD32. If you are also using it - uncheck the following checkbox:

Setup -> Advanced setup -> Antivirus and antispyware -> Protocol filtering -> "Enable application protocal content filtering"

Simple disabling of antivirus or firewall *doesn't* help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe nitpicking and maybe just a typ-o but sometimes the silliest things can drive us nuts;

your statement:"Raven.Server started and binded to port **8082**. I initialize DataStore in the following way:"

your code example reads:
"var store = new DocumentStore() { Url = "http://localhost:**8022**" };"

the port in your title is **8082** and the port in your example is **8022**.

I realize your typ-o may not be in your actual code but it never hurts to check.

'm jus' sayin'

P

Comment: Thanks for pointing! This is a typ-o, unfortunately... Question updated.